# BigQuery Standard SQL, get max value from json array

Tags: sql, json, google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery column which contains STRING values like

```
col1
[{"a":1,"b":2},{"a":2,"b":3}]
[{"a":3,"b":4},{"a":5,"b":6}]
```

Now when doing a SELECT for each I want to get just the max. value of "a" in each json array for example here I would want the output of the SELECT on the table to be

```
2
5
```

Any ideas please?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY()` to retrieve each array element.  Then `JSON_EXTRACT_VALUE()`:

```
with t as (
    select '[{"a":1,"b":2},{"a":2,"b":3}]' as col union all
    select '[{"a":3,"b":4},{"a":5,"b":6}]'
)
select t.*,
       (select max(json_value(el, '$.a'))
        from unnest(JSON_QUERY_ARRAY(col, '$')) el
      )
from t;
```